# In Kotlin, what do curly brackets mean after a function name?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Kotlin beginner here: I'm going over the Jetpack Compose tutorial and I came across this code snippet:

```
@Composable
fun MessageCard(msg: Message) {
    Column {
        Text(text = msg.author)
        Text(text = msg.body)
    }
}
```

If Column is a function name, how can it be called without "()" but with {}? I'd expect it to be called like the Text function.

I've tried think about Column as an Object or a code block name, but neither makes sense.

Comment: It's a lambda parameter (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html). As a syntactic sugar you can write it outside of parenthesis. Kind of prettier for writing DSLs.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here Column {} is a function you call but you can see it more like a container. You place inside the elements you want to be placed in columns. You can see it as a container in HTML if you want. You could do something like this:

```
@Composable
fun ArtistCard() {
    Column {
        Text("Alfred Sisley")
        Text("3 minutes ago")
        Row {
            Text("Alfred Sisley")
            Text("3 minutes ago")
        }
    }
}
```

It would display something like:

Alfred Sisley

3 minutes ago

Alfred Sisley 3 minutes ago

You can read the document [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics?hl=fr#:%7E:text=Utilisez%20Column%20pour%20placer%20les%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9ments%20verticalement%20sur%20l%27%C3%A9cran.)

Comment: "Here Column {} is not a function you call" What? No, of course it is a function.

Comment: Right, my bad, I didn't express myself correctly haha

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand what the code does, it is the syntax confuses me and I can't find a Kotlin doc supporting this usage.

Comment: I did find the answer on a Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/z2al5d/kotlin_theory_behind_jetpack_compose_what_are/. Basically if last parameter of Kotlin function is a lambda, it can be move out of the parameter list and in its own code block.

Comment: @XuemingZhang The link that m0skit0 put in their comment under the question contains the documentation. It's a "trailing lambda". Here's a more direct link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas

Comment: Thanks Slaw, that is the Kotlin doc I was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

`Column` is a function that accepts a single parameter, and that parameter is a lambda function with some object (call it `Receiver` for example) as receiver.

`Column` would, somewhere in the code, be defined something like this:

```
fun Column(exec: Receiver.() -> Unit) {
   // Code to run the Column function
   // This will create or otherwise obtain an object of type Receiver
   //  and execute `exec` in its scope
}
```

I suggest using your IDE to find its definition so you can see further what's going on.

In Kotlin, lambdas are [defined within curly braces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax). Kotlin allows a [shorthand notation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas) where the normal parenthesis used for calling a function can be omitted when the last argument is a lambda function, and that notation is being used in your example. Equally you could have written:

```
Column({
   Text(text = msg.author)
   Text(text = msg.body)
})
```

but your IDE would probably suggest that you remove the outer parenthesis for clarity and to match convention.

`Receiver` is a type which exposes the `Text` function, allowing you to call `Text` within the lambda function you are passing to `Column`. So `Receiver` will be defined something like:

```
class Receiver {
   fun Text(text: String) {
      // Do something with the text, probably saving it within Receiver
      //  for later processing when `Column` is called
   }
}
```